# render glyph failed when running some qt apps

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, qt

When i run some qt apps like "openRGB" or "Telegram-Desktop" they close immediately after opening them. If i run them from terminal i get an error saying:

`render glyph failed err=13 face=0x558887d33b10, glyph=44`

The glyp code changes depending on the app.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I am using arch linux with ketnel 6.0.2-arch1-1 and Qt version 5.15.6 but i've kept getting this error since previous versions (don't know when they started)

Comment: I don't know what is not clear about the question. Some Qt apps wont open because of some kind of problem with font config. As the error doesn't say much i don't have much more info...

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by uninstalling some GNOME packages. I had different sessions (i3 and GNOME) and I removed everything related to GNOME. After uninstalling all GNOME packages with `sudo pacman -Rnc gnome` the problem was solved.